# How can I sum two fields from two different tables in laravel in api?

Tags: laravel, api

I want to add the `price` field from the `engines`table with the `buying_price` field from the `vehicles` table where we have several `purchases` of vehicles and several engines and I want to sum the final `cost` for each purchases

```
I have the following tables
```

[image]

I want to add the `price` field from the `engines`table with the `buying_price` field from the `vehicles` table where we have several `purchases` of vehicles and several engines and I want to sum the final `cost` for each purchases

I wrote the following command, but I get an error:

```
     $purchase=DB::table('purchases')
            ->leftjoin('vehicles', 'vehicles.purchase_id', '=','purchases.id')
            ->leftjoin('engines', 'engines.purchase_id','=','purchases.id') 
            ->leftjoin('suppliers', 'suppliers.id', '=', 'purchases.supplier_id')
            ->select('purchases.id','suppliers.name','purchases.purchase_date','vehicles.buying_price','engines.price')->get()
            ->collect('vehicles.buying_price','engines.price')->sum();
          return $purchase
```

`this is the the error:`

[image]

`In short, how do I add two values ​​from two different tables and show them in another table?`

Answer (score 0):

you can call back of sum instead of collect.

For example Try this:-

```
 $purchase=DB::table('purchases')
        ->leftjoin('vehicles', 'vehicles.purchase_id', '=','purchases.id')
        ->leftjoin('engines', 'engines.purchase_id','=','purchases.id') 
        ->leftjoin('suppliers', 'suppliers.id', '=', 'purchases.supplier_id')
        ->select('purchases.id','suppliers.name','purchases.purchase_date','vehicles.buying_price','engines.price')->get()
        ->sum(function($data){
        return $data->buying_price + $data->price;
        });
```